# DateTime.TryParseExact does not return correct response

Tags: c#, datetime

Why would

```
 DateTime.TryParseExact("08/10/2013", "dd/MM/yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue)
```

return false?

Comment: Because / ist the placeholder for the concrete seperator in the currentculture. If the culture is currently german / would actualy be - and thats not in the date.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use  `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead of `null`.

It tells the compiler that the format is culture-independent.

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("08/10/2013", 
                       "dd/MM/yyyy", 
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                       DateTimeStyles.None, 
                       out dateValue);`
```

If you use `null`, it is inferred as `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`(msdn: *"If provider is null, the CultureInfo object that corresponds to the current culture is used"*). Also, since it's not that clear, the problem is that / is replaced by the provided culture's date-separator. It has a special meaning. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator

Here is a running example

[image]

Comment: You should also mention that `null` is the same as `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` (msdn: _"If provider is null, the CultureInfo object that corresponds to the current culture is used"_). Also, since it's not that clear, the problem is that `/` is replaced by the provided culture's date-separator. It has a special meaning. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator

Answer (score 6):

Because you passed `null` for the IFormatProvider parameter. Try passing CultureInfo.InvariantCulture instead

**EDIT**
As others mentioned, the actual reason is that `/` in the string to parse is itself translated using the rules provided by `IFormatProvider`. When you pass `null` the default value of CultureInfo.CurrentCulture is used.

Comment: You should mention that `null` is the same as `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` (msdn: _"If provider is null, the CultureInfo object that corresponds to the current culture is used"_).

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

public static bool IsValidDateTime(string sDateTime){
        bool ret = false;

```
    string[] formats = {
        "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
        "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz"
    };

    try{
        DateTime.ParseExact(sDateTime, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None); 
        ret = true;
    }
    catch{}

    return ret;
}
```